# Youtube data API - How to know if i'm a moderator of a specified channel

Tags: youtube-api

Is there any way to know if I'm currently set as moderator for a specified channelId ?

I'm managing automation through the Youtube API and before to start them I need to check if the user that I'm impersonating through the Youtube app has been set by the user as "moderator".